# HTTPS GET API call using base64 encoding

Tags: python, https, get, header, base64

I am trying to make an HTTP GET API call to one of my server, which support HTTP basic authentication using an API key in base64 encoding. so basically I want to add my authorization header in base64 encoding to my request.

The one method of authorization I know is:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://test.com/test-API-Gateway/v0/deployments', auth=('user', 'password'), verify=False)).text

>>> print r
{"statusCode":401,"statusMsg":Unauthorized,"result":[]}
```

But my server does not return anything, since it does not take id and password for authentication, rather it needs the base64 encoding header. Can you please tell me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Python Requests library does allow you to add custom headers. You should be able to create the appropriate header (with your base64 encoding) and pass it as a parameter, like so:

```
import requests
url = 'https://test.com/test-API-Gateway/v0/deployments'
myheaders = {'my-header-param': 'somedata'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=myheaders, verify=False)).text
```

The related documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).